# Browser throws error on creating an ObjectURL of an Image Blob after consuming lot of memory

Tags: javascript, html, memory, websocket, blob

Well, I'm running into a strange Error while programming a Web Application that receives Images from a Server via WebSockets. The Server sends about 8 images per second (.bmp) to the browser. Each image has a size of about 300KB. So that's around 2.4Mbps.

The browser receives the images as binary blob:

```
//WebSocket
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.10:1337");
//Image
var camImg = new Image();

ws.onmessage = function(msg)
{
    var data = msg.data;
    // handle binary messages from server
    if (data instanceof Blob) camImg.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
};

camImg.onload = function()
{
    //draw image to canvas
    canvasCont2D.drawImage(this,0,0);
    //request next frame
    ws.send("give me the next image!");
    //delete ObjectURL
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
};
```

So until this point everything runs fine. Now I'm coming for the first problem:
As I was testing this in Chrome I watched at the TaskManager to see how many resources this coding needs. I saw there one process of Chrome that started at about 90MB Memory. Each second there were add 2.4MB. So it looks like every image i receive stays in memory. Is there any possibility to prevent this? The received blobs seem to stay under resources in Chrome developer tools, btw.

Anyway this problem leads me to the second one: The memory consumption of this process rises and rises and after some time at about 400-500MB its kind of flushed and starts again at 90MB, again rising. So long, its just a memory problem. But sometimes it could happen, that the memory is not flushed and rises up to about 600MB. At this point I don't receive any new image. The console shows an error that says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This error occurs in this line:

```
camImg.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
```

At the moment I work around this issue by catching the error event:

```
camImg.onerror = function()
{
    //request next frame anyway and wait for memory flush
    ws.send("give me the next image!");
};
```

So I'm just requesting new images because after some time the memory gets flushed again (after a few seconds) and I can receive new Images.

The same problem(s) occure using Opera as well. I guess its mainly a problem with memory consumption. Maybe a bug in browsers? Or did I made a big programming error?

I would be very thankful for any help as I have no idea left, what could be causing this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS: Windows7 64bit

Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m

Chrome Version 38.0.2068.0 canary (64-bit) : (chrome://flags/#impl-side-painting setting makes no difference).

In a prototype I'm doing,  I get exactly the same behaviour as this in chrome 35 and a recent canary build. Ok in IE and firefox. I'm running a localhost c++ websocket server about 10fps with 0.5MB images.
The chrome memory eventually goes up and something trashes the chrome too.

Moving forwards:

1) In image.onerror I call window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);  This seems to sort my memory leak out, but not the 404's.

2) When running under the F12 debugger things are so slow that I don't seem to get the problem. Thus on page I have 3 counters: 1) Blobs received count, 2) image.onload count and 3) image.onerror count. 
After approx 900 successful loads I start getting load failures. then after maybe after 50 failures, I start getting successful loads again. This pattern keeps repeating, but the numbers seem random.( This all seems to smack of some GC related  issue, but only a hunch based on experience).

3) I can fix (AKA 'bodge') this by changing ws.binaryType='arraybuffer'. I need a blob so I construct a new one based on a new Uint8Array(msg.data). Everything works fine, no load failures at all.

I'm making an unnecessary binary copy here, but it doesn't seem to make any noticeable speed difference. I'm not 100% sure what's going on here and how stable the fix is.

Most similar image loading examples on the internet don't have an onerror handler. Running such examples on my machine would result in a unexplainable memory leak. You wouldn't see the 404's unless under the debugger and lucky. There's lots of people on the internet complaining about memory leaks when loading images. Maybe it's related.

I'm going to raise this issue on the chromium forums.

hope this helps ... matt

Comment: Here' the Chromium issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=392161